# SmartCVS Already Running Error

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I have a Mac with Yosemite on it. Upon downloading SmartCVS 7.1.9 from https://www.syntevo.com/smartcvs/ , I try to run the application and receive an error that states "SmartCVS seems to already be running. Instead of running separate instances you can open multiple project windows in SmartCVS. If you are sure that no SmartCVS instance is running any more you should delete the lock file $FILE_PATH$/_lock_".

I've tried to delete the _lock_ file multiple times and that doesn't help (the lock file is empty. The application hasn't ever successfully run. Rebooting doesn't help. Deleting it from the computer and downloading it again doesn't help. Downloading previous versions has yielded the same error (7.1.3). I've tried running it from the terminal to get the crash log, but it doesn't make much sense.

In case it helps, upon downloading the first time I had a pop up stating that SmartCVS was by an unidentified publisher and couldn't open. I got around this problem found here: http://www.imore.com/how-open-apps-unidentified-developer-os-x-mountain-lion

I know that the program can work on my Mac OS since my boss has it running on her computer. Though, strangely, she did not have to deal with either of the two problems I've had to deal with.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

so at the time I posted this I also reached out to a SmartCVS community support group. They were able to solve the problem as follows:

My computer is part of a Network. As such, the files are technically stored locally since my User Home is on the Network. SmartCVS can't interact with the lock file since it's not on the local machine. Therefore in the file at "~/Library/Preferences/SmartCVS/7.1/smartcvs.properties", I needed to append the following line to the end of the file:

smartcvs.applock=false